# Error using with statement

Tags: python

Hey guys am new to python development and i tried to undrstand the use of `with`..The code i have wrote is

```
  class Mgr(object):

       def __enter__(self): pass
       def __exit__(self, ext, exv, trb):
          if ext is not None: print "no not possible"
                 print "OK I caught you"
                 return True

       def honey(self):
           print 'guli'



b = Mgr()
with b.honey() as d:
        print d
```

When i run the code it gaves me output `guli` along with an attribute error.

I know with works with context managers and is `b.honey()` a context manager ??..  Can you guys please explain me why this error occurs ..Thanx for the help..

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/c", line 18, in <module>
    with b.honey() as d:
AttributeError: __exit__`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, while `b` is a context mananger, `b.honey()` isn't.

`b.honey()` is just whatever you return from the `honey` method. In this case, you don't return anything, so it's `None`.

---

If you want `b.honey()` to return `b`, you could—just add `return self` to the end of the method. But this is kind of strange. You wouldn't normally expect using `b.honey()` in a `with` statement to "close" `b`. That would be like `with f.read(8192) as buf:` closing the file `f`. (There are some use cases where that might make sense, but not in general.)

---

Or, there's no reason `b` and `b.honey()` can't both be totally separate context managers. It's hard to think of a case where you'd want this, but if you did, you could return an instance of some other class—or use the [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def honey(self):
    print 'guli'
    yield 'this is d'
    print 'ilug'
```

---

But more likely, what you actually wanted is something like this:

```
with Mgr() as d:
    d.honey()
    print d
```

But in that case, you probably want to change the `__enter__` method to `return self`. Whatever it returns is what's going to end up in `d`.

So, for example:

```
class Mgr(object):
     def __enter__(self): 
         return self
     def __exit__(self, ext, exv, trb):
         if ext is not None: print "no not possible"
         print "OK I caught you"
         return True

    def honey(self):
        print 'guli'

with Mgr() as d:
    d.honey()
    print d
```

Now, the `with Mgr() as d` constructs and initializes an `Mgr` instance (you don't have an `__init__`, so that does nothing), then calls its `__enter__` method, which returns that instance, then assigns the result to `d`. Then it runs `d.honey()` and `print d`. And then (whether there was an exception or not) it calls `d.__exit__(…)`.

Comment: when i did this it gaves me output like `OK I caught you" and no not possible` ..but i didnt get output `gulli`

Comment: @pythonlover: Which "this" did you do? I gave three different suggestions that all do different things, and I just gave you the relevant code rather than a complete program for all of them, which makes it hard to guess which one you tried and how you may have gotten it wrong.

Comment: i tried the last method you have given me..this is my code .. http://pastebin.com/eLgtwP0i..what i need is that i need an output `gulli` without any errors

Comment: @pythonlover: When I go there, I just see "This paste has been removed!"

Comment: @abarnert seems like he have done the last method..can you just provide the full code ?

Comment: @pythonlover: OK, I fixed the indentation errors, and changed your `__enter__` method to make sense with `with Mgr() as d:`, and explained how it works.

Comment: @abarnert would you explain the `@contextmanager` method ??..whats the use of doing `@contextmanager` before a function ??..and how can i access those ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu I linked to the docs, so you can read them. I believe the docs also have a link to the PEP that first introduced the feature, which has some more examples, and a link to a wiki page with even more.

Comment: i didnt see any tutorial using `@contextmanager` with classes

Comment: @pythonlover it's no different using it in a method than using it anywhere else.